# Netsuite API integration postman

Tags: postman, netsuite, suitetalk

I am trying to integration netsuite with other application. So i am using API's to do that using postman.

I have a postman collection that i have found from google :-

https://[accountID].app.netsuite.com/app/external/integration/integrationDownloadPage.nl

but while running this collection in postman with proper credentials and details, i am getting error:-

> {
>       "type": "https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html",
>       "title": "Account-specific domain is not used",
>       "detail": "You must use account-specific domains with the REST Web Services endpoints. Go to Setup > Company > Company Information in the NetSuite UI. Your domains are listed on the Company URLs tab.",
>       "status": 403,
>       "o:errorCode": "USER_ERROR"
>   }

I have also gone through the company information page and seen urls that i am using and they are listed there.

So How can i solve this issue? Is there any configuration missing or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Was this on sandbox or production?

I recommend using the other URLs: 

SUITETALK (SOAP AND REST WEB SERVICES)

- `https://[accountID].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com`

RESTLETS

- `https://[accountID].restlets.api.netsuite.com`